# Tomcat7 Maven Web application error

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, web

i have trouble with my maven web application what was created from maven-web-archetype. i am tried deploy my "helloworldapp"  with tomcat7-maven-plugin, and it's not worked. 
my errors list is there:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building weba Maven Webapp 1.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ web ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\БОСС ЗДЕСЬ\IdeaProjects\projectb\web\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.401s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 14 13:34:27 GMT+04:00 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/109M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Users\БОСС ЗДЕСЬ\IdeaProjects\projectb>cd web                                                                                              

C:\Users\БОСС ЗДЕСЬ\IdeaProjects\projectb\web>mvn tomcat7:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building weba Maven Webapp 1.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ web >>>
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.47/tomcat-catalina-7.0.47.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.47/tomcat-catalina-7.0.47.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.47/tomcat-catalina-7.0.47.jar (1548 KB at 316.4 KB/sec
)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ web ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ web ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ web <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ web ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/web
[INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration at C:\Users\БОСС ЗДЕСЬ\IdeaProjects\projectb\web\target\tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: /web
ёхэ 14, 2015 1:39:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
ёхэ 14, 2015 1:39:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
ёхэ 14, 2015 1:39:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
ёхэ 14, 2015 1:39:44 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:855)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1051)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.
java:2973)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1899)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getDefaultWebXmlFragment(ContextConfig.java:1469)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1246)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ёхэ 14, 2015 1:39:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at file:/C:/Users/┴╬╤╤%20╟─┼╤▄/IdeaProjects/projectb/web/target/tomcat/conf/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/┴╬╤╤%20╟─┼╤▄/IdeaProjects/projectb/web/target/tomcat/conf/web.xml; lineNumber: 108;
columnNumber: 15; Error at (108, 15) : org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2687)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2719)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1054)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.
java:2973)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1899)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getDefaultWebXmlFragment(ContextConfig.java:1469)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1246)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:855)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1051)
        ... 26 more

ёхэ 14, 2015 1:39:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Occurred at line 108 column 15
ёхэ 14, 2015 1:39:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
ёхэ 14, 2015 1:39:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
ёхэ 14, 2015 1:39:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/web] startup failed due to previous errors
ёхэ 14, 2015 1:39:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/web] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application w
as stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
ёхэ 14, 2015 1:39:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.epam</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <name>weba Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.47</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    <finalName>web</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

parent's pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.epam</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Memorina</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.21</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.47</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <finalName>spring-webmvc</finalName>
    </build>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>db</module>
        <module>model</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

my web.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">

  <!-- ======================== Introduction ============================== -->
  <!-- This document defines default values for *all* web applications      -->
  <!-- loaded into this instance of Tomcat.  As each application is         -->
  <!-- deployed, this file is processed, followed by the                    -->
  <!-- "/WEB-INF/web.xml" deployment descriptor from your own               -->
  <!-- applications.                                                        -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!-- WARNING:  Do not configure application-specific resources here!      -->
  <!-- They should go in the "/WEB-INF/web.xml" file in your application.   -->


  <!-- ================== Built In Servlet Definitions ==================== -->


  <!-- The default servlet for all web applications, that serves static     -->
  <!-- resources.  It processes all requests that are not mapped to other   -->
  <!-- servlets with servlet mappings (defined either here or in your own   -->
  <!-- web.xml file).  This servlet supports the following initialization   -->
  <!-- parameters (default values are in square brackets):                  -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--   debug               Debugging detail level for messages logged     -->
  <!--                       by this servlet.  [0]                          -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--   fileEncoding        Encoding to be used to read static resources   -->
  <!--                       [platform default]                             -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--   input               Input buffer size (in bytes) when reading      -->
  <!--                       resources to be served.  [2048]                -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--   listings            Should directory listings be produced if there -->
  <!--                       is no welcome file in this directory?  [false] -->
  <!--                       WARNING: Listings for directories with many    -->
  <!--                       entries can be slow and may consume            -->
  <!--                       significant proportions of server resources.   -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--   output              Output buffer size (in bytes) when writing     -->
  <!--                       resources to be served.  [2048]                -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--   readonly            Is this context "read only", so HTTP           -->
  <!--                       commands like PUT and DELETE are               -->
  <!--                       rejected?  [true]                              -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--   readmeFile          File to display together with the directory    -->
  <!--                       contents. [null]                               -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--   sendfileSize        If the connector used supports sendfile, this  -->
  <!--                       represents the minimal file size in KB for     -->
  <!--                       which sendfile will be used. Use a negative    -->
  <!--                       value to always disable sendfile.  [48]        -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--   useAcceptRanges     Should the Accept-Ranges header be included    -->
  <!--                       in responses where appropriate? [true]         -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--  For directory listing customization. Checks localXsltFile, then     -->
  <!--  globalXsltFile, then defaults to original behavior.                 -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--   localXsltFile       Make directory listings an XML doc and         -->
  <!--                       pass the result to this style sheet residing   -->
  <!--                       in that directory. This overrides              -->
  <!--                       contextXsltFile and globalXsltFile[null]       -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--   contextXsltFile     Make directory listings an XML doc and         -->
  <!--                       pass the result to this style sheet which is   -->
  <!--                       relative to the context root. This overrides   -->
  <!--                       globalXsltFile[null]                           -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--   globalXsltFile      Site wide configuration version of             -->
  <!--                       localXsltFile This argument is expected        -->
  <!--                       to be a physical file. [null]                  -->
  <!--                                                                      -->
  <!--                                                                      -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
      <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

    </web-app>
```

Help me,please!

Comment: For starters stop mixing spring versions, `4.2.0.RELEASE` and `4.0.1.RELEASE`. Next to that your web.xml is indicating a servlet 2.3 based application you probably want a [3.0 header](http://dominikdorn.com/2010/03/web-xml-web-fragment-xml-2-3-2-4-2-5-3-0/) instead or remove the web.xml completely.

Comment: @PeterRader i've edited my post

Comment: <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
"</servlet>" is in 108 line

Comment: @PeterRader i just deleted some comments.

Comment: Ah ok, the DefaultServlet has a mismatching method... I guess in the parent's pom loads a jar who loads a different DefaultServlet. Please post the parent's pom.xml for a full debug.

Comment: @PeterRader it's already in post

Comment: @PeterRader i fix this,but now i have only  this:
ёхэ 14, 2015 2:39:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Comment: @PeterRader and nothing else.tomcat not running(

Comment: Looks like you uses different versions of tomcat in your classpath, please remove all tomcat-* dependencies from <dependencies> section (inside root and child projects). Leave it only in plugins section.

Comment: @АндрейБугаков `INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]` means the app is up and running well. Go to http://localhost:8080/